# SQL: field = other_field returns false even if they are identical (NULL values)

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, comparison

I have a difficulty because when comparing two fields in a subquery, although the fields are identical i.e. they both have NULL values, the comparison returns a FALSE result

Therfore NULL = NULL is returning FALSE

Now I know that NULLs are supposed to be compared with the IS operator, however when I compare two fields how am I supposed to know  they contain a null?  I need to compare two fields for identical data both if the values are NULL or not.

Consider this SQL:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM
fts.fts_customers_data_50360001
WHERE 
    fts.fts_customers_data_50360001.record_type = 15
    AND
    fts.fts_customers_data_50360001.mid = 103650360001
    AND NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 
            fts.temp_fees_50360001.record_type
        FROM 
            fts.temp_fees_50360001
        WHERE 
            fts.temp_fees_50360001.record_type      = fts.fts_customers_data_50360001.record_type    
            AND 
            fts.temp_fees_50360001.merch_id         = fts.fts_customers_data_50360001.mid
            AND 
            fts.temp_fees_50360001.fee_curr         = fts.fts_customers_data_50360001.currency
            AND 
            fts.temp_fees_50360001.card_scheme      = fts.fts_customers_data_50360001.card_scheme
            AND 
            fts.temp_fees_50360001.tran_type        = fts.fts_customers_data_50360001.fee_type
            AND 
            fts.temp_fees_50360001.area             = fts.fts_customers_data_50360001.region
            AND 
            fts.temp_fees_50360001.srvc_type        = fts.fts_customers_data_50360001.card_type
    );
```

In the query above,

fts.temp_fees_50360001.card_scheme = fts.fts_customers_data_50360001.card_scheme

both have NULL values inside but the comparison returns false .. too bad

ANY IDEAS WOULD BE MUCH APPRECIATED

Comment: "NULL = NULL is returning FALSE" not true. `NULL = NULL` returns `UNKNOWN` - the *third* truth value in SQL's three-valued logic. To see that your assertion is incorrect, try `NOT (NULL = NULL)` and you'll see that it's still not a match.

Comment: It looks like your database isn't normalised if you need to compare 7 data fields.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the others have pointed out, `NULL` cannot be compared with `NULL`.

In Postgres you can shorten your expressions by using the operator `IS DISTINCT FROM` which is a null-safe replacement for `<>`. In your case you'd need to use `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` to compare for equality (looks a bit the wrong way round but unfortunately there is no corresponding `IS EQUAL TO` defined in the SQL standard).

[From the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html):

> *Ordinary comparison operators yield null (signifying "unknown"), not true or false, when either input is null. For example, 7 = NULL yields null, as does 7 <> NULL. When this behavior is not suitable, use the IS [ NOT ] DISTINCT FROM constructs:*

So, instead of

```
(fts.temp_fees_50360001.record_type = fts.fts_customers_data_50360001.record_type
 OR (fts.temp_fees_50360001.record_type IS NULL 
     AND fts.fts_customers_data_50360001.record_type IS NULL)
)
```

you can use:

```
(fts.temp_fees_50360001.record_type IS NOT DISTINCT FROM  fts.fts_customers_data_50360001.record_type)
```

to handle NULL values automatically. The condition looks a bit strange if you want to compare for equality but it still is quite short.

Comment: +1 nice approach for PostgreSQL, may be the best one

Comment: @RomanPekar: `IS DISTINCT FROM` is actually ANSI SQL (so not really "Postgres specific) - although I don't know any other DBMS that implements that.

Comment: thanks, I always knew that PostgreSQL is the closest one to implement all features of ANSI SQL :) I work with SQL Server almost 100% of the time, and it's hard to keep all these differences in mind..

Answer (score 4):

First of all, use aliases for your tables, your query will be MUCH more readable:

```
select *
from fts.fts_customers_data_50360001 as d
where
    d.record_type = 15 and
    d.mid = 103650360001 and
    not exists 
    (
        select *
        from fts.temp_fees_50360001 as f
        where
            f.record_type = d.record_type and 
            f.merch_id = d.mid and
            f.fee_curr = d.currency and
            f.card_scheme = d.card_scheme and
            f.tran_type = d.fee_type and
            f.area = d.region and
            f.srvc_type = d.card_type
    )
```

As for your question, there's several ways to do this, for example, you can use syntax like this:

```
...
(
    f.card_scheme is null and d.card_scheme is null or
    f.card_scheme = d.card_scheme
)
...
```

Or use `coalesce` with some value that couldn't be stored in your column:

```
...
coalesce(f.card_scheme, -1) = coalesce(d.card_scheme, -1)
...
```

Recently I also like using `exists` with `intersect` for this type of comparisons:

```
...
exists (select f.card_scheme, f.tran_type intersect select d.card_scheme, d.tran_type)
...
```

Just a side note - you have to be careful when writing queries like this and check query plans to be sure your indexes are used.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, `null` is never equal to `null`. The only way to get a true result for a comparison with null is via the special tests:

```
IS NULL
IS NOT NULL
```

In your case, you must cater specifically for the "two nulls" case being considered equal:

```
AND (fts.temp_fees_50360001.card_scheme = fts.fts_customers_data_50360001.card_scheme
  OR (fts.temp_fees_50360001.card_scheme IS NULL
    AND fts.fts_customers_data_50360001.card_scheme IS NULL)
)
```

There's no getting around dealing with it (although there are a few variations).

Answer (score 0):

The following inner SELECT works (but I give no guarantee regarding performance):

```
    SELECT 
        fts.temp_fees_50360001.record_type
    FROM 
        fts.temp_fees_50360001
    WHERE 
        (fts.temp_fees_50360001.record_type      = fts.fts_customers_data_50360001.record_type
        OR (fts.temp_fees_50360001.record_type IS NULL AND fts.fts_customers_data_50360001.record_type IS NULL))
        AND 
        (fts.temp_fees_50360001.merch_id         = fts.fts_customers_data_50360001.mid
        OR (fts.temp_fees_50360001.merch_id IS NULL AND fts.fts_customers_data_50360001.mid IS NULL))
        AND 
        (fts.temp_fees_50360001.fee_curr         = fts.fts_customers_data_50360001.currency
        OR (fts.temp_fees_50360001.fee_curr IS NULL AND fts.fts_customers_data_50360001.currency IS NULL))
        AND 
        (fts.temp_fees_50360001.card_scheme      = fts.fts_customers_data_50360001.card_scheme
        OR (fts.temp_fees_50360001.card_scheme IS NULL AND fts.fts_customers_data_50360001.card_scheme IS NULL))
        AND 
        (fts.temp_fees_50360001.tran_type        = fts.fts_customers_data_50360001.fee_type
        OR (fts.temp_fees_50360001.tran_type IS NULL AND fts.fts_customers_data_50360001.fee_type IS NULL))
        AND 
        (fts.temp_fees_50360001.area             = fts.fts_customers_data_50360001.region
        OR (fts.temp_fees_50360001.area IS NULL AND fts.fts_customers_data_50360001.region IS NULL))
        AND 
        (fts.temp_fees_50360001.srvc_type        = fts.fts_customers_data_50360001.card_type 
        OR (fts.temp_fees_50360001.srvc_type IS NULL AND fts.fts_customers_data_50360001.card_type))
```